# Bootstrap - Remove box-shadow on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i created a webpage with bootstrap. I have a `.corset` inside the `.container` class. The `.corset` has the following spec:

```
.corset {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px rgba(186,186,186,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px rgba(186,186,186,1);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px rgba(186,186,186,1);
}
```

I want to achieve that the box-shadow is set to none on mobile devices. I know that there are helper classes like `.hidden-xs` or `.visible-*-*` but i do not want to hide the .corset, i just want to edit its specs on mobiles. Is there a helper available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use media queries for this. Bootstrap has  great support for [that](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) as well.

For example, in your case would be something like that:

```
/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .corset {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: While true please consider elaborating the answer.

Comment: @HashemQolami, I was on it

Comment: The `@screen-*`s are LESS variables, you should replace them with absolute lengths in `px` unit.

Comment: @HashemQolami Ok, I have left them, in order to give a more generic answer. But if you think this way is better, there it is.

Comment: +1 Better to stick with CSS as the OP haven't tagged LESS IMO.

Answer (score -2):

Solution 1
Using @media queries: specific rules for small screen

```
    @media only screen {
        /*small screen css*/
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {
        /*desktop css*/
    }
```

But you cant truly detect mobiles without user-agents sniffing via javascript.
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
is an example.
Then add a `.mobile` class to the `html` element, and then define a `.mobile .corset{}` rule